# Loading an induction machine after starting unloaded

Tags: induction-motor, torque

I work with compressors and usually the starting characteristic for fixed speed machines with starters is that the machine starts unloaded (star starter), after that the compressor unit is loaded and the motor starter switches to delta. Now my main question is regarding the torque characteristics. I know the motor has a torque/speed curves and the compressor unit has also its own torque/speed characteristics (load curve). The thing is that I don't know how the combined load-motor toque/speed characteristics is going to be. I ask this because we often deal with motor selection and this is done by the supplier of the motor but I would like to understand more about this.

We have load torque curves with starting torque for example being 450 Nm. and we also get torque curves from motor supplier specifying starting torque of around for example 1020 Nm. So clearly the motor can handle both the starting torque and rated torque at the rated speed. But it is possible for the motor supplier to change the design and give us a machine with lower starting torque and hence lower price. Also we sometime we have to change the supplier so the starting torque and breakdown changes and I don't know if the motor can handle the compressor unit or not. that's why I wanna know more about the torque characteristics of the machine and motor combined. I don't know should I look more at the starting torque or the breakdown torque; or put both the load curve and motor curve on top of each other and observe the characteristics.

I really appreciate your help.